# How to create a "Diagram package"?

Tags: packages, diagrams

After looking for some material about Venn Diagrams, for example that (Ed Sandifer. How Euler Did It, Venn Diagrams Mathematical Association of America, January 2004) and after checking different questions on Tex.stackexchange like [How to draw Venn diagrams (especially: complements) in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex), I realized there was no Venn Diagram package and that may be an interesting idea.

What if you wanna trace the Venn diagram for 4 different circles ? What about the Euler diagram ? (difference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

I'm just a beginner in LaTeX, I have some knowledge in C and some basic knowledge in LaTeX but I have no idea of how to build a LaTeX package.

I just have an idea of what the requirements should be :

- Compatible with PDFLatex
- Considered as a float by the compiler
- Highly configurable in terms of

  - Type of diagram : Venn, Euler, conceptual three axis diagram ([here](http://nextlevelobjects.com/images/threeAxis_4b.jpg)), ...
  - Number of sets
  - Colors
  - Size (scale, width)
- And it would take the past parameters as arguments and options of the package

If you have some tutorial for doing it, I'd be glad to start the code but right now I have no idea of how to do it.

I just wanted this idea to be somewhere, just like the diagram idea [Diagrams package that allows to draw computer buffers (memory diagrams)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/diagrams-package-that-allows-to-draw-computer-buffers-memory-diagrams).

Comment: How about all possible Venn diagrams http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67395/how-to-generate-all-possible-venn-diagrams-with-the-case-below-efficiently

Comment: Good idea, but this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum or a development site. What should be the "correct answer"? I guess the question should be closed, if there's no concrete point to focus on.

Comment: This is interesting, but as Stefan points out this is not a question, so perhaps you should consider editing it to make it a question. Also, you should have a look at the [venndiagram package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram).

Comment: I just edited it to "how to develop a diagram package", is this correct now ?

Comment: I don't think it's correct. You might want to pose specific questions (e.g., "How can I deal with package options in this MWE?", "Why doesn't this option work  in this MWE?", etc.).

Comment: I suggest you start playing with package `tikz` (having the manual (it's actually a manual for `tikz` *and* `pgf`) open. Try drawing the diagrams you need. When you'll have a specific question, people at this site will be glad to help. ---And who knows, maybe at some point your code will become general enough to be packaged!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer perse (since it's been pointed out that, as it stands, this isn't much of a question), but it is the advice you're looking for.

Take a look at all your resources available to you (LaTeX Wiki, TeXBook, etc.) and familiarize yourself with TeX's control structures.  After you're comfortable *reading* TeX code, hop into a simple document class (such as `exam.cls`) or package and look at how *they* put it together.  Don't look at just one, either -- you might be unfortunate enough to see one that wasn't coded well, or worse incorrect.

Good luck.