# Sidebar for curriculum not working skipping page

Tags: page-breaking, sidebyside

I am having a problem in LaTeX.  I am trying to keep the sidebar consistent from page to page.

The template I am using is called `AltaCV` Template in overleaf (sorry can only post 2 links because of my rep).

Although the problem is, as you can see in the pictures below, that the "sidebar" writings are not consistent and since the left side in the first page goes beyond one page the second page does not follow.

I really don't know what to do. I really would like to keep it consistent, such that the left side continues on a second page and the right side does the same.

[image: Everything looks fine here]

[image: But then left hand side disappears]

Here is part of the code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is an sample CV template created using altacv.cls
% (v1.1, 21 November 2016) written by LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com). Now compiles with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you need to pass whatever options to xcolor
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons 
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome and academicon fonts
%% and packages. 
%% See texdoc.net/pkg/fontawecome and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols.
%% 
%% Compile with LuaLaTeX for best results. If you
%% want to use XeLaTeX, you may need to install
%% Academicons.ttf in your operating system's font 
%% folder.


% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

% Change the font if you want to.

% If using pdflatex:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}

% If using xelatex or lualatex:
% \setmainfont{Lato}

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{Mulberry}{HTML}{72243D}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{Sepia}
\colorlet{accent}{Mulberry}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\name{Your Name Here}
\tagline{Your Position or Tagline Here}
\photo{2.8cm}{Globe_High}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{your@email.com}
  \phone{000-00-0000}
  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{Location, COUNTRY}
  \homepage{www.homepage.com/}
  \twitter{@twitterhandle}
  \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/yourid}
  \github{github.com/yourid}
  %% You MUST add the academicons option to \documentclass, then compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, if you want to use \orcid or other academicons commands.
%   \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}
}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want. Extend the right margin by 8cm (=6.8cm marginparwidth + 1.2cm marginparsep)
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-8cm}
\makecvheader
\end{adjustwidth}

%% Provide the file name containing the sidebar contents as an optional parameter to \cvsection.
%% You can always just use \marginpar{...} if you do
%% not need to align the top of the contents to any
%% \cvsection title in the "main" bar.
\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Experience}

\cvevent{Job Title 1}{Company 1}{Month 20XX -- Ongoing}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Job Title 2}{Company 2}{Month 20XX -- Ongoing}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Projects}

\cvevent{Project 1}{Funding agency/institution}{Project duration}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Details
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Project 2}{Funding agency/institution}{Project duration}{}
A short abstract would also work.

\medskip

\cvsection{A Day of My Life}

% Adapted from @Jake's answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
% \wheelchart{outer radius}{inner radius}{
% comma-separated list of value/text width/color/detail}
\wheelchart{1.5cm}{0.5cm}{%
  6/8em/accent!30/{Sleep,\\beautiful sleep}, 
  3/8em/accent!40/Hopeful novelist by night,
  8/8em/accent!60/Daytime job,
  2/10em/accent/Sports and relaxation,
  5/6em/accent!20/Spending time with family
}

\clearpage
\cvsection[page2sidebar]{Publications}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faBook}{Books}},type=book]

\divider

\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faFileTextO}{Journal Articles}},type=article]

\divider

\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faGroup}{Conference Proceedings}},type=inproceedings]


\end{document}
```

Sorry I am a noob in LaTeX, and definitely that's not the right rating in my curriculum, I took a picture before modifying it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  We try to avoid greetings and thanks.  You can thank in a comment and by giving reputation points.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know, I am new to TEX.SE

Comment: How do you close the thread? I have found a solution, should I write the solution as answer?

Comment: Answer your own question with the solution you've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution, I just had to shift part of the curriculum that was potruding on the second page to the sidebar on the first page.

Now it actually looks nicer.

[image]

```
\vspace{\baselineskip}


\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 2
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}



\cvsection{My Life Philosophy}

\begin{quote}
``Something smart or heartfelt, preferably in one sentence.''
\end{quote}

\cvsection{Most Proud of}

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Fantastic Achievement}{and some details about it}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faHeartbeat}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}

\divider

\cvachievement{\faHeartbeat}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}

\cvsection{Strengths}

\cvtag{Hard-working} 
\cvtag{Eye for detail}
\cvtag{Motivator \& Leader}

\divider\smallskip

\cvtag{C++}
\cvtag{Embedded Systems}
\cvtag{Statistical Analysis}

\cvsection{Languages}

\cvskill{English}{5}
\divider

\cvskill{Spanish}{4}
\divider

\cvskill{German}{3}

%% Yeah I didn't spend too much time making all the 
%% spacing consistent... sorry. Use \smallskip, \medskip, 
%% \bigskip, \vpsace etc to make ajustments.
\medskip

\cvsection{Education}

\cvevent{Ph.D.\ in Your Discipline}{Your University}{Sept 2002 -- June 2006}{}
Thesis title: Wonderful Research

\divider

\cvevent{M.Sc.\ in Your Discipline}{Your University}{Sept 2001 -- June 2002}{}

\divider

\cvevent{B.Sc.\ in Your Discipline}{Stanford University}{Sept 1998 -- June 2001}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `\addnextpagesidebar` command to link a new sidebar in next page.

```
%% If the NEXT page doesn't start with a \cvsection but you'd
%% still like to add a sidebar, then use this command on THIS
%% page to add it. The optional argument lets you pull up the 
%% sidebar a bit so that it looks aligned with the top of the
%% main column.
% \addnextpagesidebar[-1ex]{page2sidebar}
```

Ref : https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/issues/11