# How to add labels in two lines in a ring diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the label of a 2D donut pie chart with pgf-plot how can I bring the label to the second line if its a long label?

Basically, I am referring to [2D ring diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82727/create-a-ring-diagram-in-tex) and would like to add the labels in two lines (I have big labels)

I am quite new to LaTeX and unable to change it. can anyone help me in doing this. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

I would add `align=...` to the text nodes and then add line breaks (`\\`) to the text.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.8cm}
\def\outerradius{2.2cm}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
    \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
        \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

        % Rotate so we start from the top
        \begin{scope}[
            rotate=90,
        ]
            % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
            \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

                % Calculate the percent value
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
                % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

                % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
                \pgfmathparse{
                    (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
                } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}

                % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
                \fill [\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius)
                    -- (-\newcumnum:\innerradius)
                    arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius)
                    -- cycle
                ;

                % Draw the data labels
                \draw  [*-,thin] node [
                    append after command={
                        (\midangle:\midradius pt)
                        -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex)
                        -- (\tikzlastnode)
                    }
                ] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [
                    xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,
%                    inner sep=0pt,          % <-- commented
                    outer sep=0pt,
                    anchor=\textanchor,
                    % ---------------------------------------------------------
                    % add `align=...' and add linebreaks (`\\') to the text
                    align=left,
                    % ---------------------------------------------------------
                ] {\name: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%};

                % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
                \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
            }
        \end{scope}
%      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    % Usage: \wheelchart{<value1>/<colour1>/<label1>, ...}
    \wheelchart{
        26/cyan/Corporate,
        28/orange/This is a very long label \\ that is wrapped over more \\ than one line,
        33.5/yellow/Chimique,
        12.5/blue!50!red/Rhodia%
    }
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 4):

The perhaps simplest option is to add `text width` to the options of the respective nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.8cm}
\def\outerradius{2.2cm}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
    \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
        \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}

      % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

      % Rotate so we start from the top
      \begin{scope}[rotate=90]

      % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
      \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

            % Calculate the percent value
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
            % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

            % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
            \pgfmathparse{
               (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
            } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}

            % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
            \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

            % Draw the data labels
            \draw  [*-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius
            pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) --
            (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex)
            [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, 
            text width=3cm, %<-added
            anchor=\textanchor]{\name: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%};


            % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }

      \end{scope}
%      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Usage: \wheelchart{<value1>/<colour1>/<label1>, ...}
\wheelchart{26/cyan/Corporate bla bla bla,  28/orange/Plastique, 33.5/yellow/Chimique, 12.5/blue!50!red/Rhodia}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

Multiple lines in the data can be achieved by using `\\` for a line break.

The percentages are automatically computed and can be used with `\WCperc`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  data=\WCvarC: \WCperc,
  lines=0.4,
  lines ext=0.5,
  lines ext left anchor=east,
  lines ext right anchor=west,
  lines sep=-0.2,
  lines style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {
        \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];
      }
    }
  },
  perc precision=1,
  radius={1.8}{2.2},
]{%
  26/cyan/Corporate\\and a\\long text,
  28/orange/Plastique\\and another\\long text,
  33.5/yellow/Chimique\\and a\\short text,
  12.5/blue!50!red/Rhodia%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```