# How to prevent polyglossia german and pgfmath from clashing?

Tags: polyglossia, pgfmath, german, quotation

I've recently tried the tikz wheel from this other thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423907/140011 - it all works fine until I switched polyglossia to german.

This fails with

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathparse{(5? "west" : "east" )}  % Apprently these quotes are  the culprit.
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathparse{(5? 5 : 4 )} % This does not make sense but works
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As we can easily see the quotes around `east` seem to be problem.

How can I bypass this?

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` (as wrong as it might look :-)

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik - I am so relieved now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Phelype Oleinik beat me to this in a comment.

The `polyglossia` package is setting the `"` character active in order to enable `babel`-style shorthands, which breaks it in pgf.  You want to load the `babel` TikZ library for compatibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathparse{(5? "west" : "east" )}  % Apprently these quotes are  the culprit.
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can additionally give either `\usepackage{polyglossia}` or `\setdefaultlanguage{german}` the option `[babelshorthands=false]`, although this is not enough for your MWE to compile.

You could also use `\tikz[handle active characters in code]` to enable active characters in node text, without breaking pgf parsing.