# How to fix vertical spacing issues in a CV template?

Tags: spacing, two-column, document-classes, double-sided, cv

I am using [this](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV) template for a CV. However, for some reason I am getting incomplete sections over the two pages, for example:

[image]

How can I make **section 4** appear in the other side of the page (top of the second one)? Also **Section 5** is not appearing in the second side of the second page. Any idea of how to fix this issues? I tried to use `\vspace` but its not working.

The minimum example:

main: `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}


\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}


\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{academicons}
  \usepackage{fontawesome}
  \usepackage{marvosym}
  \usepackage{lipsum}


\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to

\definecolor{hanblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}

\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{hanblue}
\colorlet{accent}{hanblue}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\name{John DO}
\tagline{\Large position}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{\href{mail@.com}}
  \phone{3209840932 0938 23948}
%  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{worldwide, world}
  \linkedin{www.myexample.com}
  \faGlobe \ \url{www.myexample.com} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
  \href{www.myexample.com}{site}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 \href{www.myexample.com}{\textit{site2}}
}

\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Section 1}

\cvevent{Section 1}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\cvevent{Section 2}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}



\cvevent{Section 3}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
\vfill
```

`alta.cls`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is altacv.cls (v1.1.5, 1 December 2018) written by
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com).
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%
%%
% Contributions:
% - https://github.com/akreuzer Added ragged2e option (5 Nov 2018)
% - https://github.com/stefanogermano Fixed bad boxes and undefined font shape (July 2018)
% - https://github.com/foohyfooh Fixed blank spaces in \cvevent and bad link in README.md (June 2018)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
%% v1.4: Detect TL2018 to handle accented characters in class information
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}
\ProvidesClass{altacv}[2018/12/01 AltaCV v1.1.5, yet another alternative class for a résumé/curriculum vitae.]

%% v1.1: Optionally load academicons
\newif\if@academicons
\DeclareOption{academicons}{\@academiconstrue}
%% v1.1.3: Choice of round/square photo
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\newif\if@raggedtwoe
\DeclareOption{ragged2e}{\@raggedtwoetrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{extarticle}

\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}

%% v1.1.5: added for convenience
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

%% v1.1: Optionally load academicons
%% v1.1.5: Handle different versions of academicons
\if@academicons
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    %% academicons in TL2018 doesn't require
    %% Academicons to be installed in OS fonts
    %% so can be loaded directly
    \@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{%
      \RequirePackage{academicons}
    }{%
      % TL2017
      \@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2017/04/01}{%
        \@ifpackagelater{academicons}{2018/03/01}{%
          \RequirePackage{academicons}
        }{%
          \let\ori@newfontfamily\newfontfamily%
          \renewcommand{\newfontfamily}[2]{}
          \RequirePackage{academicons}
          \let\newfontfamily\ori@newfontfamily
          \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
        }
      }{% TL2016 requires the package to be loaded before
        % the version can be checked. Only added because
        % Overleaf v1 still runs TL2016; will be removed
        % when v1 is completely retired.
          \let\ori@newfontfamily\newfontfamily%
          \renewcommand{\newfontfamily}[2]{}
          \RequirePackage{academicons}
          \let\newfontfamily\ori@newfontfamily
          \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
      }
    }
  \else
    \ClassError{AltaCV}{academicons unsupported by latex or pdflatex. Please compile with xelatex or lualatex}{Please compile with xelatex or lualatex to use the academicons option}
  \fi
\fi

\if@raggedtwoe
  \RequirePackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\fi

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\newcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0.5em,nosep,itemsep=0.25\baselineskip,after=\vskip0.25\baselineskip}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\itemmarker}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{multirow,tabularx}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
% \RequirePackage{marginfix}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\newcommand{\emailsymbol}{\faAt}
\newcommand{\phonesymbol}{\faPhone}
\newcommand{\homepagesymbol}{\faChain}
\newcommand{\locationsymbol}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
\newcommand{\twittersymbol}{\faTwitter}
\newcommand{\githubsymbol}{\faGithub}
\newcommand{\orcidsymbol}{\aiOrcid}
\newcommand{\mailsymbol}{\faEnvelope}

\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\photo}[2]{\def\@photo{#2}\def\@photodiameter{#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\printinfo{\emailsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mailaddress}[1]{\printinfo{\mailsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\printinfo{\phonesymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\homepage}[1]{\printinfo{\homepagesymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\twitter}[1]{\printinfo{\twittersymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[1]{\printinfo{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\github}[1]{\printinfo{\githubsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\printinfo{\orcidsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\printinfo{\locationsymbol}{#1}}

\newcommand{\personalinfo}[1]{\def\@personalinfo{#1}}

\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-2em}}{}%
    \raggedright\color{emphasis}%
    {\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\large\bfseries\color{accent}\@tagline\par}
    \medskip
    {\footnotesize\bfseries\@personalinfo\par}
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter}
    \if@normalphoto
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\@photo}
    \else
      \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
    \fi%
    \end{minipage}\par}{}%
  \endgroup\medskip
}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\color{accent}\itshape\large}{\par}

\newcommand{\cvsection}[2][]{%
  \bigskip%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\marginpar{\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\baselineskip}\raggedright\input{#1}}}%
  {\color{heading}\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#2}}\\[-1ex]%
  {\color{heading}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}\medskip
}

\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \smallskip%
  {\color{emphasis}\large\bfseries{#1}\par}\medskip
}

% v1.1.4: fixes inconsistent font size
\newcommand{\cvevent}[4]{%
  {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
  \ifstrequal{#3}{}{}{{\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#3}}}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{{\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}#4}}}\par
  \medskip\normalsize
}

\newcommand{\cvachievement}[3]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2em} @{\hspace{1ex}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\Large\color{accent}#1} & \bfseries\textcolor{emphasis}{#2}\\
  & #3
  \end{tabularx}%
  \smallskip
}

\newcommand{\cvtag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

\newcommand{\cvskill}[2]{%
\textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\hfill
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
  \space{\ifnumgreater{\x}{#2}{\color{body!30}}{\color{accent}}\ratingmarker}}\par%
}

% Adapted from @Jake's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[4][0]{%
    \begingroup\centering
    \def\innerradius{#3}%
    \def\outerradius{#2}%
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}%
    \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#4} {%
        \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}%
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult%
    }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalrot}{-90 + #1}

      % Rotate so we start from the top
      \begin{scope}[rotate=\totalrot]

      % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
      \foreach \value/\width/\colour/\name in {#4} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

            % Calculate the percent value
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
            % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

            % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
            \pgfmathparse{
               (-\midangle>180?"west":"east")
            } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathparse{
               (-\midangle>180?"flush left":"flush right")
            } \edef\textalign{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle<180)}

            % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
            \filldraw[draw=white,fill=\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

            % Draw the data labels
            \draw  [*-,thin,emphasis] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=1ex, outer sep=0pt, text width=\width,anchor=\textanchor,align=\textalign,font=\small,text=body]{\name};
            % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }
      \end{scope}
%      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}\par
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\cvref}[3]{%
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\par
  \begin{description}[font=\color{accent},style=multiline,leftmargin=1.35em]
  \item[\normalfont\emailsymbol] #2
  \item[\small\normalfont\mailsymbol] #3
  \end{description}
%   \medskip
}

\newenvironment{cvcolumn}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\raggedright}{\end{minipage}}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
%% For removing numbering entirely when using a numeric style
% \setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
% \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\defbibheading{pubtype}{\cvsubsection{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}

% v1.1.2: make it easier to add a sidebar aligned with top of next page
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\addsidebar}[2][]{\marginpar{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\vspace*{#1}}%
  \input{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\addnextpagesidebar}[2][]{\afterpage{\addsidebar[#1]{#2}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \color{body}
  \raggedright
}
```

`page1sidebar.tex`:

```
\cvsection{Section 2}

\cvevent{Section 3}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[2]

\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Section 3}

\cvevent{Section 4}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\cvsection{Section 4}

\cvevent{Section 5}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}
```

`page2sidebar.tex`:

```
\cvsection{Section 5}


\cvevent{Section 3}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


sample.bib

the bib, part of the template (see link)
```

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). That is the way to say "Thank you" here!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to rephrase your sidebar content for page one to be shorter or you have to move the last part to sidebar page two.

You also should rephrase/shorten or dividing section 2 on the left side of page 1. The part not fitting on page has to be moved to page two then.

You mark the starting of page 2 with

```
 \cvsection[\jobname-page2sidebar]{Section 3}
```

Please see that I used `\jobname-` to insert the file name of your main tex file, for example `mwe` if you use file `mwe.tex` for your cv. The reason I want not to overwrite your original sidebar files with my mwe, because I used package `filecontents` (**only for this mwe, you keep your files using!**) to get a compiling mwe containing three tex files ...

Please see this code (important code changings marked with `<=======`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-page1sidebar.tex}
\cvsection{Section 2}

\cvevent{Section 3}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[2]

\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Section 3}

\cvevent{Section 4}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-page2sidebar.tex}
\cvsection{Section 4} % <========================================= moved

\cvevent{Section 5}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\cvsection{Section 5}


\cvevent{Section 3}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

\geometry{%
  left=1cm,right=9cm,
  marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,
  top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm
}

\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{academicons}
  \usepackage{fontawesome}
  \usepackage{marvosym}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{hanblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{hanblue}
\colorlet{accent}{hanblue}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\name{John DO}
\tagline{\Large position}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{\href{mail@mail.com}{text}}
  \phone{3209840932 0938 23948}
%  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{worldwide, world}
  \linkedin{www.myexample.com}
  \faGlobe \ \url{www.myexample.com} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
  \href{www.myexample.com}{site}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 \href{www.myexample.com}{\textit{site2}}
}

\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

\cvsection[\jobname-page1sidebar]{Section 1}% <=========================

\cvevent{Section 1}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\cvevent{Section 2}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    %\item \lipsum[4] % <======================================= deleted
    %\item \lipsum[4]
    %\item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}

\cvsection[\jobname-page2sidebar]{Section 3} % <================= page 2

\cvevent{Section 3}{place}{date}{place.}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
    \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

and resulting page 1

[image: page 1]

and page 2

[image: page 2]

As you can see now section 5 in the sidebar 2 is too long.

The template you are using forces you to rephrase your text until it fits the page(s) ...

Comment: Is there any way of modify the template in order to allowing to have lager columns?

Comment: @anon No, the layout is designed for single pages. You have to keep that in mind. The defined colums in this template can not span pages ...