# Controlling the full size of a wheel chart

Tags: cv

Hello I'm new to LaTeX but I'm trying to make a wheel chart fit in a left side bar for a CV made with `altacv.cls`:

```
\wheelchart{1.5cm}{0.5cm}{%
  7/10em/accent!30/Modélisation \ UML,
  25/9em/accent!60/ Programmation orientée \ Objets,
  5/13em/accent!10/\footnotesize\\ Compétences Génie logiciel,
  20/15em/accent!40/Algorithmique,
  5/8em/accent!20/\footnotesize XML,
  30/9em/accent/Python /& bibliothèques annexes,
  5/8em/accent!20/Qt,
}
```

Is there a way to control how much space it takes in order to fit taking in mind the word arowed to the section 
ps : there is a duplicated arrow that I can't delete. 
Thanks in advance and I really appreciate your help

## EDIT:

Actually it's compilable it's out of template i have found maybe that's why here is the link
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer-using-altacv/gtqfpbwncfvp

and it work pretty well for me aside from being not centred in the allocated space
about of the side bar 
ps the chart is actully in the other side 
and sry for the tags i don't know a lot about latex feel free to change them in order to help other benfit from this question

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Then please consider to accept it. And to upvote it after reaching rep 15 or more. That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help"!

Comment: I am new to LaTeX as well and I am working on the same CV template. I am trying to bring this wheelchart towards the left (change the alignment).

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is a missunderstanding.

Please have a look to the line

```
5/13em/accent!10/\footnotesize\\ Compétences Génie logiciel,
```

and have a look to the following line from `altacv.cls`

```
\foreach \value/\width/\colour/\name in {#4} { 
% and later we found
...  text width=\width ...
```

You can see that `\width`, the second value in the line `13em` is used to define the length of the shown text `\footnotesize\\ Compétences Génie logiciel`.

That is the reason you get the following result

[image: resulting wheel]

Now you can use for example (see code changings marked with `<======`)

```
\wheelchart{1.9cm}{0.7cm}{% <=========================================== {1.5cm}{0.5cm}
  7/10em/accent!30/Modélisation \ UML,
  25/9em/accent!60/ Programmation orientée \ Objets,
  5/10em/accent!10/\footnotesize\\ Compétences Génie logiciel, % <====== 5/13em -> 5/10em
  20/15em/accent!40/Algorithmique,
  5/8em/accent!20/\footnotesize XML,
  30/9em/accent/Python /& bibliothèques annexes,
  5/8em/accent!20/Qt
}
```

to get the wheel better centered in the cv.

With the complete code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is an example CV created using altacv.cls (v1.1.5, 1 December 2018) written by
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com), based on the
% Cv created by BusinessInsider at http://www.businessinsider.my/a-sample-resume-for-marissa-mayer-2016-7/?r=US&IR=T
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome and academicon fonts
%% and packages.
%% See texdoc.net/pkg/fontawecome and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Lato}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi
\usepackage{fontawesome} % <============================================

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{3E0097}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}


\begin{document}
\name{Marissa Mayer}
\tagline{Business Woman \& Proud Geek}
% Cropped to square from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marissa_Mayer#/media/File:Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_(cropped).jpg, CC-BY 2.0
\photo{2.5cm}{mmayer-wikipedia-cc-by-2_0}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{mmayer@yahoo-inc.com}
%   \phone{000-00-0000}
  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{Sunnyvale, CA}
  \homepage{marissamayr.tumblr.com/}
  \twitter{@marissamayer}
  \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/marissamayer}
%   \github{github.com/mmayer} % I'm just making this up though.
%   \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000} % Obviously making this up too. If you want to use this field (and also other academicons symbols), add "academicons" option to \documentclass{altacv}
}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

%% Provide the file name containing the sidebar contents as an optional parameter to \cvsection.
%% You can always just use \marginpar{...} if you do
%% not need to align the top of the contents to any
%% \cvsection title in the "main" bar.
\cvsection[mmayer-p1sidebar]{Experience}

\cvevent{President \& CEO}{Yahoo!}{July 2012 -- Ongoing}{Sunnyvale, CA}
\begin{itemize}
\item Led the \$5 billion acquisition of the company with Verizon -- the entity which believed most in the immense value Yahoo!\ has created
\item Acquired Tumblr for \$1.1 billion and moved the company's blog there
\item Built Yahoo's mobile, video and social businesses from nothing in 2011 to \$1.6 billion in GAAP revenue in 2015
\item Tripled the company's mobile base to over 600 million monthly active users and generated over \$1 billion of mobile advertising revenue last year
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Vice President of Location \& Services}{Google}{Oct 2010 -- July 2012}{Palo Alto, CA}
\begin{itemize}
\item Position Google Maps as the world leader in mobile apps and navigation
\item Oversaw 1000+ engineers and product managers working on Google Maps, Google Places and Google Earth
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Vice President of Search Products \& UX}{Google}{2005 --  2010}{Palo Alto, CA}

\divider

\cvevent{Product Manager \& UI Lead}{Google}{Oct 2001 -- July 2005}{Palo Alto, CA}

\begin{itemize}
\item Appointed by the founder Larry Page in 2001 to lead the Product Management and User Interaction teams
\item Optimized Google's homepage and A/B tested every minor detail to increase usability (incl.~spacing between words, color schemes and pixel-by-pixel element alignment)
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{A Day of My Life}

% Adapted from @Jake's answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
% \wheelchart{outer radius}{inner radius}{
% comma-separated list of value/text width/color/detail}
% Some ad-hoc tweaking to adjust the labels so that they don't overlap
\wheelchart{1.9cm}{0.7cm}{% <=========================================== {1.5cm}{0.5cm}
  7/10em/accent!30/Modélisation \ UML,
  25/9em/accent!60/ Programmation orientée \ Objets,
  5/10em/accent!10/\footnotesize\\ Compétences Génie logiciel, % <====== 5/13em -> 5/10em
  20/15em/accent!40/Algorithmique,
  5/8em/accent!20/\footnotesize XML,
  30/9em/accent/Python /& bibliothèques annexes,
  5/8em/accent!20/Qt
}

\end{document}
```

you get the better result:

[image: bettere wheel in cv]

Comment: thanks for your reply at first i had troubles understanding the proportions that's why i  tried to tweak the overall proportion

Comment: in the same template pricisly in the side bar the content get displayed twice even after having putting the command /clearpage (doesn't exist in the template )thanks again

Comment: @saitama sorry, I do not understand your second comment. If that is a new question, please **ask a new question**, add there the used code and mark in the screenshot of your result what the culprit is ...

Comment: @saitama Please see this page is no forum! Please do not change your question in an comment. Ask a new question. This is an question and (one or more) answer page. It allows people searching for their problem in the asked questions. and find solutions to the given issue (in the unchanged question!) ...