# altacv: change head position and alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, overleaf, altacv

I use [this](https://www.overleaf.com/project/6094a7637f832d74b37f5e10) altacv template.
I have change photo position thanks to [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494766/insert-the-picture-on-the-left) and moved sidebar thanks to [that](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/issues/19).
But the matter is that there is photo requirements for my cv: 4cm * 6cm size.
I've added 7cm photo:

```
\photo{7cm}{photo_name}
```

But the header takes up too much space now.

May I:

1. Change the position of the header?
2. Change the alignment to the left?
3. Start the main part of CV right after the header?
4. Leave sidebar as it is.

I've uploaded [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmrDT.jpg) of what I have now and what I'd like to have.

**My MWE:**

```
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is an example CV created using altacv.cls (v1.1.5, 1 December 2018) written by
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com), based on the
% Cv created by BusinessInsider at http://www.businessinsider.my/a-sample-resume-for-marissa-mayer-2016-7/?r=US&IR=T
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter} 
    \if@normalphoto
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\@photo}
    \else
      \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
    \fi%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-2em}}{}%
    \raggedleft\color{emphasis}%
    {\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\large\bfseries\color{accent}\@tagline\par}
    \medskip
    {\footnotesize\bfseries\@personalinfo\par}
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{\end{minipage}\par}{}%
  \endgroup\medskip
}
\makeatother

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome and academicon fonts
%% and packages.
%% See texdoc.net/pkg/fontawecome and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=9cm,right=1cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

\reversemarginpar
\patchcmd{\fullwidth}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}{}}
  {}{}
% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Carlito}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{3E0097}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{37474F}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\name{Name Surname}
\tagline{long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long- position}
% Cropped to square from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marissa_Mayer#/media/File:Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_(cropped).jpg, CC-BY 2.0
\photo{7cm}{Photo_name}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
    \printinfo{e-mail}{aaa@gmail.com} \\
    \printinfo{phone}{123456789} \\
    \printinfo{skype}{blabla} \\

%   \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000} % Obviously making this up too. If you want to use this field (and also other academicons symbols), add "academicons" option to \documentclass{altacv}
}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

%% Provide the file name containing the sidebar contents as an optional parameter to \cvsection.
%% You can always just use \marginpar{...} if you do
%% not need to align the top of the contents to any
%% \cvsection title in the "main" bar.

\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Career}

\cvevent{blablablablablabla)}{blablablablablabla}{Date1 -- Date2}{Remote}
\begin{itemize}
    \item bla-bla-bla.
    \item bla-bla-bla.
    \item bla-bla-bla.
    
\end{itemize}
\cvtag{bla} 
\cvtag{bla}
\cvtag{bla}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

**Page1Sidebar:**

```
    \cvsection{Achievements}

\cvachievement{\faTrophy}{BlaBlaBlaBlaBla}{BlaBlaBlaBlaBla}
\cvtag{Bla} 
\cvtag{Bla}
\cvtag{Bla}
\cvtag{Bla}
\cvtag{Bla}
```

I will very appreciate your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce your output and add it directly into your question.

Comment: Thank you for your welcoming! I've added MWE.

Comment: Your MWE is not working. In particular there are two `\documentclass` clauses, the part before `\documentclass` cannot work there, and the template is not accessible.

Comment: Pieter, my apologies. Does it work now? I didn't include altacv.cls.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: You have to put your own image in `\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_cr.jpg}`. Test the code using  `\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{example-image}`

Comment: I update the answer, Please try again the complete code as it its.  It looks from the error you got that something went wrong coping the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Most of the requirements can be met. The only limitation is that, by design, the CV header is constructed with two minipages side by side, the image on the left and the personal data on the right, with equal height, so the text in the second "column" (Career) cannot flow up.

What can be done is to insert a short paragraph with a title, keeping its format with the general design.

Three new commands were added:

(1)  `\layoutphoto{<t, c or b alignment of both minipages>{<image width>}{<image file name>}` to set the image in the left minipage. `\photo` is not longer used.

You can play with the vertical position the two minipages. Now is set as `t` (top) using a generic square 4*4 cm image: `\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{example-image}`

If you have  a 4*6 cm photo called `Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_cr.jpg`, as your MWE indicates, use:
`\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_cr.jpg}`.

(2) `\shorttitle` and `\shorttext` allow the insertion of a short paragraph and its title, with the format of the other sections.

**Using a generic photo to test the code:** `layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{example-image}` (4*4 cm)

[image: xx]

**Using a 4*6cm photo** called `Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_cr.jpg`

[image: z]

This is the code. The lines changed or added are marked.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\usepackage{adjustbox}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<< 
\usepackage{csquotes}% needed for biblatex added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cvsectionxtra}[2]{%  add short paragraph to the header <<<<<<< added 
    \medskip    
    \ifdefempty{#1}{}{\color{heading}\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}\\[-1.7ex]%    
    \color{heading}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}
    \medskip
    \ifdefempty{#2}{}{\normalfont\color{body}\raggedright\large{#2}}
}

\newcommand{\layoutphoto}[3]{%% set the photo <<< added
    \def\photoset{#1}       
    \def\photowidth{#2} 
    \def\photoname{#3}
    \def\@photodiameter{#2}
    \def\@photo{#3}
}   

\renewcommand{\photo}[2]{}% do nothing
\newcommand{\shorttitle}{}
\newcommand{\shorttext}{}

\renewcommand{\makecvheader}{%  %changed <<<<<<<<<<
    \begingroup
    \adjustbox{valign=\photoset}{\begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter} 
        \if@normalphoto
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\photowidth,keepaspectratio]{\photoname} 
        \else
        \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\photoname}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
        \fi%
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill%
    {\adjustbox{valign=\photoset}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-3em}%             
        \raggedright\color{emphasis}%
        {\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
        \medskip
        {\large\bfseries\color{accent}\@tagline\par}
        \medskip
        {\footnotesize\bfseries\@personalinfo\par}
        \bigskip    
        {\cvsectionxtra{\shorttitle}{\shorttext}} % short paragraph added
        \medskip
        \hfill
        \end{minipage}}\par}%
    \endgroup\medskip
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel} 

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=9cm,right=1cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

\reversemarginpar
\patchcmd{\fullwidth}
{\begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
    {\begin{adjustwidth}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}{}}
        {}{}
    
\ifxetexorluatex
% If using xelatex or lualatex:
\setmainfont{Carlito}
\else
% If using pdflatex:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{VividPurple}{HTML}{3E0097}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{37474F}
\colorlet{heading}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{accent}{VividPurple}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%%%%%%%%% Set extra content in CV header <<<<<<<<<<< added
\renewcommand{\shorttitle}{Something smart}

\renewcommand{\shorttext}{Our ideas, in the case of the Ideal of pure reason, are by their very nature contradictory.  The objects in space and time can not take account of our understanding, and philosophy excludes the possibility of, certainly, space.}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% SET PHOTO LAYOUT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%% \layoutphoto{<t, c or b>{<image width>}{<image file name>}
%\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_cr.jpg} %
\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{example-image} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added PUT YOUR OWN PHOTO
%%% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
\name{Name Surname}
\tagline{long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long- position}
    
% Cropped to square from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marissa_Mayer#/media/File:Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_(cropped).jpg, CC-BY 2.0
%\photo{10cm}{Marissa_Mayer_May_2014_cr.jpg} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Do NOT USED ANYMORE

\personalinfo{%
    % Not all of these are required!
    % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
    \printinfo{e-mail}{aaa@gmail.com} \\
    \printinfo{phone}{123456789} \\
    \printinfo{skype}{blabla} \\
}

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
    \makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

%% Provide the file name containing the sidebar contents as an optional parameter to \cvsection.
\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Career}    

\cvevent{blablablablablabla)}{blablablablablabla}{Date1 -- Date2}{Remote}

\begin{itemize}
\item bla-bla-bla.
\item bla-bla-bla.
\item bla-bla-bla.  
\end{itemize}

\cvtag{bla} 
\cvtag{bla}
\cvtag{bla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Simon! Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. There are no errors, but photo doesn't appear after compilation. Instead, I've got right on the page: {[width=4cm,keepaspectratio]marissa.jpg valign=t [fill overzoom image=marissa.jpg]circle[radius=0.5]}

Comment: @Lisbeth Try again the complete above code using `\layoutphoto{t}{4cm}{example-image}`

Comment: now it works! I do deeply appreciate your help.