# Draw a pie chart with a blank circle inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, pgf-pie

I want to draw a tikzpicture pie chart look with legends look like this:[image]

How do I do that ?

Comment: Welcome! It is really easy to do that (you tag this already with pgf-pie) but it is cumbersome to punch in the data from a screen shot. So please show us what you have tried.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82727) and the linked posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relaxing in the time of Covid-19.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{12*360/100}
\fill[red!70] (0,0) circle(\r);
\fill[orange] (0,0)--(90:\r) arc(90:{90-\a}:\r)--cycle;
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{45*360/100}
\fill[lime!80!black] (0,0)--(90-\a:\r) arc(90-\a:{90-\a-\b}:\r)--cycle;
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{36*360/100}
\fill[cyan] (0,0)--(90-\a-\b:\r) arc(90-\a-\b:{90-\a-\b-\c}:\r)--cycle;
\fill[white] (0,0) circle(\r/2);
\path (current bounding box.north) node[above=5mm,font=\sffamily]
{Average Daily Activity};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[rect/.pic={\draw[#1,line width=3mm] (90:.25)--(-90:.25);}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={minimum height=8mm,minimum width=3cm,anchor=center,font=\sffamily,text=black!80},
column 2/.style={nodes={text width=4mm,align=right}},
column 3/.style={nodes={minimum width=2cm,text width=10mm,align=right}},
row 1/.style={nodes={font=\bfseries\sffamily,text width=2cm,text=black,align=center}},
]{
Hours & \% & Total\\
5am - 11am&12&6.158\\
11am - 5pm&45&22.168\\
5pm - 11pm&36&18.015\\
11pm - 5am&6&3.078\\
};
\foreach \i/\icolor in {2/orange,3/lime!80!black,4/cyan,5/red!70}
\draw[gray]
(m-\i-1.north west)--(m-\i-3.north east)
(m-\i-1.west)+(0:.2) pic{rect=\icolor};
\draw[gray]
(m-5-1.south west)--(m-5-3.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, you got bored indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

A Schrödinger's cat said, from the [`pgf-pie` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie) you can get pretty close to what you ask. Luckily for you I just happen to have done one yersterday.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \pie[text=legend,sum=100,rotate=40,radius=2.5,
         before number=\phantom,after number=,
        ] {
        12/{5am -- 11am},
        45/{11am -- 5pm},
        36/{5pm -- 11pm},
        6/{11pm -- 5am}
        }
    \path[fill=white,draw=black, thick] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, and I don't know why, I can't modify the lines to be of style `draw=none` not even when using some `every path/.append style` keys.

Here is the proposed result
[image]

Comment: Thank you! You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4,text-series-to-math=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WCvarB] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC & \WCvarD & \WCperc & \WCvarA},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-2.5) {%
      \begin{tblr}[expand=\WClegend]{
        colspec={lrlrS[table-format=5.0]},
        column{2}={rightsep=0pt},
        cell{2-Z}{2}={appto={--}},
        column{3}={leftsep=0pt},
        row{1}={guard,font=\bfseries}
      }
       & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Hours & & \SetCell[c=1]{c} \unit{\percent} & Total\\\hline
      \WClegend\hline
      \end{tblr}%
    };
  },
  radius={1}{2},
  title=Average Daily Activity
]{%
  6158/BurntOrange/5am/11am,
  22168/SpringGreen/11am/5pm,
  18015/Cerulean/5pm/11pm,
  3078/Maroon/11pm/5am%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```