# Using commands from different document class

Tags: macros, document-classes, cv

I am creating a document with class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{altacv}
```

I want to use a command `\cvdoubleitem` which is available in class `moderncv`. How to achieve this?

### Tested methods

I explored the class file of the `moderncv` and included the command defining this functionality as shown below:

```
\newcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{}
```

I used the command as shown below:

```
\cvdoubleitem[5mm]{1}{2}{3}{4}
```

It did not work. No change in the output.

Comment: The actual macro is defined in used style files. They are part of moderncv package.

Comment: Thank you. I will check sty files and update the question accordingly.

Comment: `\newcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{}` defines the command to take 5 arguments and produce no output. The specific definition in moderncv probably relies on the rest of the moderncv layout and may not easily adapt to your code, we certainly can not help with that if you do not show your code.

Answer (score 1):

The command is defined differently for each style of `moderncv`. Depending on which variant you would like to use in your CV, you can copy the definition from the respective `moderncvbodyVERSION.sty` from [github](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv), for example in `moderncvbodyi.sty`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}
```

or `moderncvbodyiii.sty`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\hintstyle{#2}: #3\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\ifstrempty{#4}{}{\hintstyle{#4}: }#5\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, command `\cvdoubleitem` is defined depending from the used style of moderncv. It also depends on several other macros (for example: `\cvitem`) and some used length (for example `\doubleitemcolumnwidth`) defined in `moderncv.cls` and the several variants of `moderncvbodyX.sty` with `X` from `i` until `vi`.

Because you did not name the used style of `moderncv`, I simply guess for now `casual`, that means `moderncvbodyi.sty` is used.

To get an compiling command `\cvdoubleitem` you need the following code in your preamble:

```
% <=====================================================================
\usepackage{calc}
% makes a resume line 2 headers and their corresponding text
% usage: \cvdoubleitem[spacing]{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2}
\newcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}

\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
  
\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
% creates a length if not yet defined
\newcommand*{\@initializelength}[1]{%
  \ifdefined#1
  \else%
    \newlength{#1}\fi%
  \setlength{#1}{0pt}}
  
\@initializelength{\hintscolumnwidth}             
\@initializelength{\separatorcolumnwidth}         
\@initializelength{\maincolumnwidth}
\@initializelength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}
\makeatother

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
  \setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\textwidth-\leftskip-\rightskip-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}%
  \setlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}%
% <=====================================================================
```

With the following complete MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This is an sample CV template created using altacv.cls
% (v1.1.5, 1 December 2018) written by LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com). Now compiles with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you need to pass whatever options to xcolor
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome and academicon fonts
%% and packages.
%% See texdoc.net/pkg/fontawecome and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Lato}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{lato}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{Mulberry}{HTML}{72243D}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{Sepia}
\colorlet{accent}{Mulberry}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% <=====================================================================
\usepackage{calc}
% makes a resume line 2 headers and their corresponding text
% usage: \cvdoubleitem[spacing]{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2}
\newcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#5\end{minipage}}}

\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
  
\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\makeatletter
% creates a length if not yet defined
\newcommand*{\@initializelength}[1]{%
  \ifdefined#1
  \else%
    \newlength{#1}\fi%
  \setlength{#1}{0pt}}
  
\@initializelength{\hintscolumnwidth}             
\@initializelength{\separatorcolumnwidth}         
\@initializelength{\maincolumnwidth}
\@initializelength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}
\makeatother

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
  \setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\textwidth-\leftskip-\rightskip-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}%
  \setlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}%
% <=====================================================================


\begin{document}

\name{Your Name Here}
\tagline{Your Position or Tagline Here}
\photo{2.8cm}{Globe_High}
\personalinfo{%
  % Not all of these are required!
  % You can add your own with \printinfo{symbol}{detail}
  \email{your@email.com}
  \phone{000-00-0000}
  \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
  \location{Location, COUNTRY}
  \homepage{www.homepage.com/}
  \twitter{@twitterhandle}
  \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/yourid}
  \github{github.com/yourid}
  %% You MUST add the academicons option to \documentclass, then compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, if you want to use \orcid or other academicons commands.
  % \orcid{orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}
}

\cvdoubleitem{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2} % <=======================

%% Make the header extend all the way to the right, if you want.
\begin{fullwidth}
\makecvheader
\end{fullwidth}

%% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
% \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}

%% Provide the file name containing the sidebar contents as an optional parameter to \cvsection.
%% You can always just use \marginpar{...} if you do
%% not need to align the top of the contents to any
%% \cvsection title in the "main" bar.
\cvsection[sample-p1sidebar]{Experience}

\cvevent{Job Title 1}{Company 1}{Month 20XX -- Ongoing}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Job Title 2}{Company 2}{Month 20XX -- Ongoing}{Location}
\begin{itemize}
\item Job description 1
\item Job description 2
\end{itemize}

\cvsection{Projects}

\cvevent{Project 1}{Funding agency/institution}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Details
\end{itemize}

\divider

\cvevent{Project 2}{Funding agency/institution}{Project duration}{}
A short abstract would also work.

\medskip

\cvsection{A Day of My Life}

% Adapted from @Jake's answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
% \wheelchart{outer radius}{inner radius}{
% comma-separated list of value/text width/color/detail}
\wheelchart{1.5cm}{0.5cm}{%
  6/8em/accent!30/{Sleep,\\beautiful sleep},
  3/8em/accent!40/Hopeful novelist by night,
  8/8em/accent!60/Daytime job,
  2/10em/accent/Sports and relaxation,
  5/6em/accent!20/Spending time with family
}

\clearpage
\cvsection[page2sidebar]{Publications}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faBook}{Books}},type=book]

\divider

\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faFileTextO}{Journal Articles}},type=article]

\divider

\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faGroup}{Conference Proceedings}},type=inproceedings]

%% If the NEXT page doesn't start with a \cvsection but you'd
%% still like to add a sidebar, then use this command on THIS
%% page to add it. The optional argument lets you pull up the
%% sidebar a bit so that it looks aligned with the top of the
%% main column.
% \addnextpagesidebar[-1ex]{page3sidebar}


\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Because you did not tell us details about your wished result I left the finding of the correct lengthes to you ...