# new to tex & struggling to compile complex .tex docs

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I am running an up to date Arch Linux.

I am a new to tex.

I have tried the latest available `texmaker` package and
the latest available `MikTex`package, which has the apparent advantage of automatically downloading all stylesheet and font dependencies, etc, as needed by any .tex document.

In texmaker I can compile very basic documents and render a pdf on the fly.

The most basic documents are not an issue.

However if I try to compile something like this, see code below,

[www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-nicolasomar-fork/htfpmrwhbwpw](http://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-nicolasomar-fork/htfpmrwhbwpw)

I get all sorts of dependency compile issues.

With TexMaker I tried finding all necessary files, fonts etc, and putting all these in the same directory as the .tex file, which helped a bit, but the number of files texmaker seems to need for a relativley complex document seems endless.

Is there a font / style library for texmaker that is comprehensive and up to date, and how would I add it so texmaker can see it?

While I think texmaker has a nicer look and feel than MikTex, I loaded MikTex becasue it apparently loads additional requirements (fonts style sheets etc) on demand.

However with Miktex I get an error

`Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException' what():  MiKTeX encountered an internal error. Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.`

cv.tex file pasted below

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% cv.tex, that's this file   
%
% This is an sample CV template created using altacv.cls
% (v1.3, 10 May 2020) written by LianTze Lim (liantze at gmail.com). Now compiles with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
% This fork/modified version has been made by Nicolás Omar González Passerino (nicolas.passerino at gmail.com, 15 Oct 2020)
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you need to pass whatever options to xcolor
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome5 and academicons fonts
%% and packages.
%% See http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontawesome5 and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,columnsep=0.75cm}

% The paracol package lets you typeset columns of text in parallel
\usepackage{paracol}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% ----- LIGHT MODE -----
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{PrimaryColor}{HTML}{001F5A}
\definecolor{SecondaryColor}{HTML}{0039AC}
\definecolor{ThirdColor}{HTML}{F3890B}
\definecolor{BackgroundColor}{HTML}{E2E2E2}
\colorlet{name}{PrimaryColor}
\colorlet{tagline}{PrimaryColor}
\colorlet{heading}{PrimaryColor}
\colorlet{headingrule}{ThirdColor}
\colorlet{subheading}{SecondaryColor}
\colorlet{accent}{SecondaryColor}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\pagecolor{BackgroundColor}   
% ----- DARK MODE -----
%\definecolor{BackgroundColor}{HTML}{242424}
%\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{6F6F6F}
%\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{ABABAB}
%\definecolor{PrimaryColor}{HTML}{3F7FFF}
%\colorlet{name}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{tagline}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{heading}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{headingrule}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{subheading}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{accent}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{emphasis}{LightGrey}
%\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
%\pagecolor{BackgroundColor}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
%% \addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
    \name{John Doe}
    \tagline{Test Developer}
    %% You can add multiple photos on the left or right
    \photoL{4cm}{john-doe}
    
    \personalinfo{
        \email{john_doe@email.com}\smallskip
        \phone{+01-2345-678901}
        \location{City, Country}\\
        \linkedin{johnDoe}
        \github{johnDoe}
        \dev{johnDoe}
        %\homepage{nicolasomar.me}
        %\medium{nicolasomar}
        %% You MUST add the academicons option to \documentclass, then compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, if you want to use \orcid or other academicons commands.
        % \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}
        %% You can add your own arbtrary detail with
        %% \printinfo{symbol}{detail}[optional hyperlink prefix]
        % \printinfo{\faPaw}{Hey ho!}[https://example.com/]
        %% Or you can declare your own field with
        %% \NewInfoFiled{fieldname}{symbol}[optional hyperlink prefix] and use it:
        % \NewInfoField{gitlab}{\faGitlab}[https://gitlab.com/]
        % \gitlab{your_id}
    }
    
    \makecvheader
    %% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
    % \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}
    
    %% Set the left/right column width ratio to 6:4.
    \columnratio{0.25}

    % Start a 2-column paracol. Both the left and right columns will automatically
    % break across pages if things get too long.
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        % ----- STRENGTHS -----
        \cvsection{Strengths}
            \cvtag{One}
            \cvtag{Two}
            \cvtag{Three}
            \cvtag{Four}
            \cvtag{Five}
            \cvtag{Six}
            \cvtag{Seven}
            \cvtag{Eight}
            \cvtag{Nine}
            \cvtag{Ten}
            \medskip
            
            \cvtag{Red}
            \cvtag{Yellow}
            \cvtag{Blue}
            \cvtag{Green}
            \cvtag{Violet}
            \cvtag{Orange}
        % ----- STRENGTHS -----
        
        % ----- LEARNING -----
        \cvsection{Learning}
            \cvtag{Uno}
            \cvtag{Dos}
            \cvtag{Tres}
            \cvtag{Cuatro}
            \cvtag{Cinco}
            \cvtag{Seis}
            \cvtag{Siete}
            \cvtag{Ocho}
            \cvtag{Nueve}
            \cvtag{Diez}
            \medskip
            
            \cvtag{Rojo}
            \cvtag{Amarillo}
            \cvtag{Azul}
            \cvtag{Verde}
            \cvtag{Violeta}
            \cvtag{Naranja}
            \cvtag{Marron}
            \cvtag{Blanco}
            \cvtag{Gris}
            \cvtag{Negro}
        % ----- LEARNING -----
        
        % ----- LANGUAGES -----
        \cvsection{Languages}
            \cvlang{Lang 1}{Native}\\
            \divider
            
            \cvlang{Lang 2}{Basic / A2}
            %% Yeah I didn't spend too much time making all the
            %% spacing consistent... sorry. Use \smallskip, \medskip,
            %% \bigskip, \vpsace etc to make ajustments.
            \smallskip
        % ----- LANGUAGES -----
            
        % ----- REFERENCES -----
        \cvsection{References}
            \cvref{Ref 1}{ref-1}
            \divider
            
            \cvref{Ref 2}{ref-2}
            \divider
            
            \cvref{Ref 3}{ref-3}
            \smallskip
        % ----- REFERENCES -----
        
        % ----- MOST PROUD -----
        % \cvsection{Most Proud of}
        
        % \cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Fantastic Achievement}{and some details about it}\\
        % \divider
        % \cvachievement{\faHeartbeat}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}\\
        % \divider
        % \cvachievement{\faHeartbeat}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}
        % ----- MOST PROUD -----
        
        % \cvsection{A Day of My Life}
        
        % Adapted from @Jake's answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
        % \wheelchart{outer radius}{inner radius}{
        % comma-separated list of value/text width/color/detail}
        % \wheelchart{1.5cm}{0.5cm}{%
        %   6/8em/accent!30/{Sleep,\\beautiful sleep},
        %   3/8em/accent!40/Hopeful novelist by night,
        %   8/8em/accent!60/Daytime job,
        %   2/10em/accent/Sports and relaxation,
        %   5/6em/accent!20/Spending time with family
        % }
        
        % use ONLY \newpage if you want to force a page break for
        % ONLY the current column
        \newpage
        
        %% Switch to the right column. This will now automatically move to the second
        %% page if the content is too long.
        \switchcolumn
        
        % ----- ABOUT ME -----
        \cvsection{About Me}
            \begin{quote}
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            \end{quote}
        % ----- ABOUT ME -----
        
        % ----- EXPERIENCE -----
        \cvsection{Experience}
            \cvevent{Charge }{| Company}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item First item
                \item Second item
                \item Third item
            \end{itemize}
            \divider
            
            \cvevent{Charge }{| Company}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item First item
                \item Second item
                \item Third item
            \end{itemize}
        % ----- EXPERIENCE -----
        
        % ----- EDUCATION -----
        \cvsection{Education}
            \cvevent{Title }{| Institution}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item GPA: 1,23
            \end{itemize}
            \divider
            
            \cvevent{Title }{| Institution}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item GPA: 1,23
            \end{itemize}
        % ----- EDUCATION -----
        
        % ----- PROJECTS -----
        \cvsection{Projects}
            \cvevent{Project 1 }{\cvrepo{| \faGithub}{https://github.com/user/repo}\cvrepo{| \faGlobe}{https://repo-demo.com/}}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
            \divider
            
            \cvevent{Project 1 }{\cvrepo{| \faGitlab}{https://gitlab.com/user/repo}\cvrepo{| \faGlobe}{https://repo-demo.com/}}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
        % ----- PROJECTS -----
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

altacv.cls file pasted below

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% altacv.cls, this file
%
% This is an sample CV template created using altacv.cls
% (v1.3, 10 May 2020) written by LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com). Now compiles with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
% This fork/modified version has been made by Nicolás Omar González Passerino (nicolas.passerino@gmail.com, 15 Oct 2020)
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you need to pass whatever options to xcolor
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}

%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome5 and academicons fonts
%% and packages.
%% See http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontawesome5 and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,columnsep=0.75cm}

% The paracol package lets you typeset columns of text in parallel
\usepackage{paracol}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% ----- LIGHT MODE -----
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{PrimaryColor}{HTML}{001F5A}
\definecolor{SecondaryColor}{HTML}{0039AC}
\definecolor{ThirdColor}{HTML}{F3890B}
\definecolor{BackgroundColor}{HTML}{E2E2E2}
\colorlet{name}{PrimaryColor}
\colorlet{tagline}{PrimaryColor}
\colorlet{heading}{PrimaryColor}
\colorlet{headingrule}{ThirdColor}
\colorlet{subheading}{SecondaryColor}
\colorlet{accent}{SecondaryColor}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\pagecolor{BackgroundColor}   
% ----- DARK MODE -----
%\definecolor{BackgroundColor}{HTML}{242424}
%\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{6F6F6F}
%\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{ABABAB}
%\definecolor{PrimaryColor}{HTML}{3F7FFF}
%\colorlet{name}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{tagline}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{heading}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{headingrule}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{subheading}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{accent}{PrimaryColor}
%\colorlet{emphasis}{LightGrey}
%\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
%\pagecolor{BackgroundColor}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}

% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
%% \addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
    \name{John Doe}
    \tagline{Test Developer}
    %% You can add multiple photos on the left or right
    \photoL{4cm}{john-doe}
    
    \personalinfo{
        \email{john_doe@email.com}\smallskip
        \phone{+01-2345-678901}
        \location{City, Country}\\
        \linkedin{johnDoe}
        \github{johnDoe}
        \dev{johnDoe}
        %\homepage{nicolasomar.me}
        %\medium{nicolasomar}
        %% You MUST add the academicons option to \documentclass, then compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, if you want to use \orcid or other academicons commands.
        % \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}
        %% You can add your own arbtrary detail with
        %% \printinfo{symbol}{detail}[optional hyperlink prefix]
        % \printinfo{\faPaw}{Hey ho!}[https://example.com/]
        %% Or you can declare your own field with
        %% \NewInfoFiled{fieldname}{symbol}[optional hyperlink prefix] and use it:
        % \NewInfoField{gitlab}{\faGitlab}[https://gitlab.com/]
        % \gitlab{your_id}
    }
    
    \makecvheader
    %% Depending on your tastes, you may want to make fonts of itemize environments slightly smaller
    % \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\small}
    
    %% Set the left/right column width ratio to 6:4.
    \columnratio{0.25}

    % Start a 2-column paracol. Both the left and right columns will automatically
    % break across pages if things get too long.
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        % ----- STRENGTHS -----
        \cvsection{Strengths}
            \cvtag{One}
            \cvtag{Two}
            \cvtag{Three}
            \cvtag{Four}
            \cvtag{Five}
            \cvtag{Six}
            \cvtag{Seven}
            \cvtag{Eight}
            \cvtag{Nine}
            \cvtag{Ten}
            \medskip
            
            \cvtag{Red}
            \cvtag{Yellow}
            \cvtag{Blue}
            \cvtag{Green}
            \cvtag{Violet}
            \cvtag{Orange}
        % ----- STRENGTHS -----
        
        % ----- LEARNING -----
        \cvsection{Learning}
            \cvtag{Uno}
            \cvtag{Dos}
            \cvtag{Tres}
            \cvtag{Cuatro}
            \cvtag{Cinco}
            \cvtag{Seis}
            \cvtag{Siete}
            \cvtag{Ocho}
            \cvtag{Nueve}
            \cvtag{Diez}
            \medskip
            
            \cvtag{Rojo}
            \cvtag{Amarillo}
            \cvtag{Azul}
            \cvtag{Verde}
            \cvtag{Violeta}
            \cvtag{Naranja}
            \cvtag{Marron}
            \cvtag{Blanco}
            \cvtag{Gris}
            \cvtag{Negro}
        % ----- LEARNING -----
        
        % ----- LANGUAGES -----
        \cvsection{Languages}
            \cvlang{Lang 1}{Native}\\
            \divider
            
            \cvlang{Lang 2}{Basic / A2}
            %% Yeah I didn't spend too much time making all the
            %% spacing consistent... sorry. Use \smallskip, \medskip,
            %% \bigskip, \vpsace etc to make ajustments.
            \smallskip
        % ----- LANGUAGES -----
            
        % ----- REFERENCES -----
        \cvsection{References}
            \cvref{Ref 1}{ref-1}
            \divider
            
            \cvref{Ref 2}{ref-2}
            \divider
            
            \cvref{Ref 3}{ref-3}
            \smallskip
        % ----- REFERENCES -----
        
        % ----- MOST PROUD -----
        % \cvsection{Most Proud of}
        
        % \cvachievement{\faTrophy}{Fantastic Achievement}{and some details about it}\\
        % \divider
        % \cvachievement{\faHeartbeat}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}\\
        % \divider
        % \cvachievement{\faHeartbeat}{Another achievement}{more details about it of course}
        % ----- MOST PROUD -----
        
        % \cvsection{A Day of My Life}
        
        % Adapted from @Jake's answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729/226
        % \wheelchart{outer radius}{inner radius}{
        % comma-separated list of value/text width/color/detail}
        % \wheelchart{1.5cm}{0.5cm}{%
        %   6/8em/accent!30/{Sleep,\\beautiful sleep},
        %   3/8em/accent!40/Hopeful novelist by night,
        %   8/8em/accent!60/Daytime job,
        %   2/10em/accent/Sports and relaxation,
        %   5/6em/accent!20/Spending time with family
        % }
        
        % use ONLY \newpage if you want to force a page break for
        % ONLY the current column
        \newpage
        
        %% Switch to the right column. This will now automatically move to the second
        %% page if the content is too long.
        \switchcolumn
        
        % ----- ABOUT ME -----
        \cvsection{About Me}
            \begin{quote}
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            \end{quote}
        % ----- ABOUT ME -----
        
        % ----- EXPERIENCE -----
        \cvsection{Experience}
            \cvevent{Charge }{| Company}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item First item
                \item Second item
                \item Third item
            \end{itemize}
            \divider
            
            \cvevent{Charge }{| Company}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item First item
                \item Second item
                \item Third item
            \end{itemize}
        % ----- EXPERIENCE -----
        
        % ----- EDUCATION -----
        \cvsection{Education}
            \cvevent{Title }{| Institution}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item GPA: 1,23
            \end{itemize}
            \divider
            
            \cvevent{Title }{| Institution}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{City, Country}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item GPA: 1,23
            \end{itemize}
        % ----- EDUCATION -----
        
        % ----- PROJECTS -----
        \cvsection{Projects}
            \cvevent{Project 1 }{\cvrepo{| \faGithub}{https://github.com/user/repo}\cvrepo{| \faGlobe}{https://repo-demo.com/}}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
            \divider
            
            \cvevent{Project 1 }{\cvrepo{| \faGitlab}{https://gitlab.com/user/repo}\cvrepo{| \faGlobe}{https://repo-demo.com/}}{Mm YYYY -- Mm YYYY}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
        % ----- PROJECTS -----
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: texmaker is an editor, miktex a tex system. They are not alternatives, you can use texmaker along with miktex. An alternative to miktex is texlive (which is also used on overleaf). I wouldn't call it a big advantage that miktex downloads on the fly. That was important in previous times, but nowadays with lots of disc space available it makes more sense to install simply everything from the start.

Comment: It is impossible to debug a statement such as `I get all sorts of dependency compile issues.`  If you provide a small but complete tex document and show the error that you get in the log, someone could help.

Comment: Note that miktex (while it has a relatively recent linux port) is almost exclusively windows. The overwhelming majority of linux tex users would be using texlive and you will find it much easier to get linux-specific help as a new user if using texlive as that is what almost all the linux community is using.

Comment: @David-Carlile, Thanks for the tip on texlive. My question was more a general set-up / linkage question - a pointer to texlive helps. Nothing I could see poped up about set-up after a fair search, last night, though I was very tired. I'd hoped to do this with only a small amount of time available, but that's probarly not going to be possible.

Comment: your linux repository should have a perfectly reasonable texlive in your standard package manager so `apt install texlive` or some such equivalent package install for arch should give you tex, then use whatever editor you use normally (I use emacs myself) there really shouldn't be any complicated setup needed. (I should say I've been installing tex for over 30 years so hard to really take an objective view on how complicated it is or is not for a newcomer:-)