# expansion behavior in tikz/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

For a long time, I thougt I understood how LaTeX expands commands. But apparently, I don't.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\r{1 and 2}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and 4); % this works
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (\r); % this causes the error
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When attempting to compile the above code, I get the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `a' or `an' (in '1 and 2').
```

Can someone explain to me why the above error happens, and what can be done to circumvent this problem?

Comment: It has to see an explicit `and` operator while parsing the content of `\r` then expands. It does not first expand and then checks the content.

Comment: How come it works in Marks answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339828/pgf-3d-pie-chart-revival?

Comment: That's an `arc` syntax not `ellipse`

Comment: I wasn't aware the expansion behavior is different between the two - why is that?

Comment: Only the developers can answer that I think. But the syntax for ellipse is the deprecated one, they recommend using `[x radius=2,y radius=4]` which is convenient in this case too since you can set the keys instead of a macro def

Comment: Doing `\edef\r` overwrites an existing macro within the current scope. `\def` followed by a single letter (or common word) macro name is never wise.

Comment: Note, from \path (or equivalent) to the terminating semicolon, tikz does its own parsing.  To insert a latex command inside a path, use \pgfextra{...}.  To insert a tikz command inside an option one should put it inside braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is so omnipresent that PGF actually develops a canonical way to bypass it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\r{1 and 2}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and 4); % this works
  \edef\pgfmarshal{\noexpand\draw (0,0) ellipse (\r);}
  \pgfmarshal
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(there are 232 `\pgf@marshal` in the whole package.)