# Different circular sectors as new logo of the International System

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

*This question does not ask the user to provide me a full MWE*, but simply to obtain any information step by step as to create different circular sectors.

[image]
This image is taken from the site: https://www.inrim.it/sites/default/files/mediaroot/eventi/logo_nuovosi.png

I have read the only the manual `pgf-pie` to build pie charts and with lot of sincerity I have seen the responses of users and I have been so scared (see here: [Multi-layer Donut Pie](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418335/multi-layer-donut-pie/418337)).

In fact, I was wondering if you need very much code to make a frontal one that is not in 3D.

I would like to make it because I absolutely don't like some symbols like `$\Delta v$` and `$K_{\text{cd}}$`.

So I only ask users for the simplest steps and no complete MWE.

Thank you (excuse me very much for not having added the link of the image and I have not specified that it serves only me and will not be published, or used improperly).

Comment: You should probably cite where you copied that image (I assume https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/img/rev-si/SI-7.jpg) The usual advice for logos is that it is a bad idea to fake them (and it may be trademark infringement) the whole point of a logo is that it is an instantly recognisable graphic denoting whatever it denotes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm so sorry, David. I forgot to insert the link to the image. I sincerely hope that I have not done any more damage. I wanted to see if there was any particular manual for creating circular sectors. I would like to point out once again that I was interested in creating it by myself, understanding the necessary steps; I thought that there were some specific packages. I don't know whether or not to remove the question. I'm waiting for instructions. Hello and thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code seems sufficiently simple and solves the rotation issue with the letters in the bottom blocks.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{arev}


\begin{document}
\Large

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
% -----------------------------------
% the \foreach-part
\foreach\n/\k/\l/\o
    [evaluate={\n as \p         using int((\n-3)*(\n-4))},
     evaluate={\n as \angle     using (90+360/14-360/7*\n)},
     evaluate={\n as \Angle     using (90+360/14-360/7*(\n+1))},
     evaluate={\n as \nsegment  using (360/7*\n)}
    ]
    in
    {0  /red/kg/$h$,
     1  /orange/m/$c$,
     2  /yellow/s/$\Delta v$,
     3  /Green/A/$e$,
     4  /RoyalBlue/K/$k$,
     5  /violet/mol/$N_A$,
     6  /Blue/cd/$K_{\textnormal{\scriptsize cd}}$%
    }
    {\fill[draw=white,line width=2.5pt,fill=\k!90!black,domain=\angle:\Angle,variable=\t]
        plot ({2*cos(\t)},{2*sin(\t)})
        -- (0,0)
        -- cycle;
     \fill[white,opacity=.4,domain=\angle:\Angle,variable=\t]
        plot ({1.2*cos(\t)},{1.2*sin(\t)})
        -- (0,0)
        -- cycle;
     \ifnum\p=0
        \path
            node[white,rotate=180-\nsegment] at (90-\nsegment:1.6) {\l}
            node[rotate=180-\nsegment,font=\small] at (90-\nsegment:.95) {\o};
     \else
        \path
            node[white,rotate=-\nsegment] at (90-\nsegment:1.6) {\l}
            node[font=\small,rotate=-\nsegment] at (90-\nsegment:.95) {\o};
     \fi
    }
% -----------------------------------
\node[circle,font=\huge,fill=white,inner sep=7pt] (0,0) {SI};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Marian thank you very much :-(  and I thank you for your response. I certainly didn't ask for an MWE as beautiful as yours, but to understand how it came about. I thought that with the only package I knew you could do. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 Mich nicer than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

You can get the colours of your logo by looking through the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) manual. If you really want the `K`, `A` and `s` rotated as in the OP this can be done but the rotations below are more natural.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \top/\mid/\col [count=\c,
                  evaluate=\c as \st using {360/7*(\c-1)+1},
                  evaluate=\c as \en using {360/7*\c-1},
                  evaluate=\st as \se using {(\st+\en)/2}
    ] in {m/c/orange,
          kg/h/red,
          cd/K_cd/purple,
          mol/N_A/purple,
          K/k/blue,
          A/e/green,
          S/\Delta v/yellow} {
       \draw[\col,fill=\col!80] (\st:1)--(\st:2)
           arc [start angle=\st, end angle=\en, radius=2]
           --(\en:1)
           arc [start angle=\en, end angle=\st, radius=1];
       \draw[\col,fill=\col!50] (\st:0.5)--(\st:1)
           arc [start angle=\st, end angle=\en, radius=1]
           --(\en:0.5)
           arc [start angle=\en, end angle=\st, radius=0.5];
       \node[white,rotate=\se-90,font=\bfseries] at (\se:1.5){\top};
       \node[rotate=\se-90,font=\scriptsize] at (\se:0.75){$\mid$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you find it natural if "6" is upside-down on a clockface? :-)

Comment: I'm so sorry I had you create a code. I'm sorry again just wanted to understand if there was a strategy with packages to use, but you just need a reasoning with tikz-pgf. I thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No more than a "9" being he right way up:) In such instances one has to infer the meaning from the orientation of related text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle reminds me of that old joke "Come in boat number 9, oops number six are you in trouble ?

Comment: Possible typo : `K_{cd}`

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The data are first stored in the macro `\WClist`.

The gaps between the slices are obtained with the key `gap`.

We set `value=1` so that each slice is the same size. We also set the key `data` empty.

The rotation of the wheel data is determined by the key `wheel data style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\def\WClist{%
  Red/kg/$h$,
  Orange/m/$c$,
  Dandelion/s/$\Delta v$,
  Green/A/$e$,
  RoyalBlue/K/$k$,
  Purple/mol/$N_{A}$,
  Blue/cd/$K_{cd}$%
}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  data=,
  gap=0.03,
  start half,
  value=1,
  wheel data pos=0.5,
  wheel data style={rotate={\WCmidangle<225?\WCmidangle-90:(\WCmidangle<315?\WCmidangle+90:\WCmidangle-90)}}
}
\wheelchart[
  middle={\huge SI},
  radius={1.2}{2},
  slices style=\WCvarA,
  wheel data={\textcolor{white}{\WCvarB}}
]{\WClist}
\wheelchart[
  radius={0.75}{1.2},
  slices style=\WCvarA!60,
  wheel data={\footnotesize\WCvarC}
]{\WClist}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was expecting your response about the logo. Thank you and happy festivities.