# how to draw a relative circlen not by pgf pie

Tags: tikz-pgf, pie

[image]

how to  draw  a relative circle like this not by pgf  pie

Comment: Why not using `pgf`?  That is the simplest way of doing it....

Comment: You may use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515772 as a starting point. It links to earlier posts of this type.

Comment: for scientific figures like that, 3D or fake-3D is not necessary. Of course, with plain TikZ, we can draw easily. Also you should provide a MWE.