# Improve the Tikz code for TeX Live 2021

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515770/3d-like-pie-chart) code. In TeX Live 2019, the `alpha0` option works correctly, but in TeX Live 2021 has no effect on output. Can anyone improve that code?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}    
\definecolor{strangegreen}{RGB}{15,111,83}
\tikzset{pics/wedge/.style={code={%
  \tikzset{wedge/.cd,#1}
  \def\kvw##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wedge/##1}}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{3*(1+sign(sin(\kvw{alpha})))+1+sign(sin(\kvw{beta}))}
  \ifcase\itest
    %0: alpha>180,beta>180
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                       (\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{beta}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(\kvw{beta}:\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius});
   \or
    %1: alpha>180,beta=0,180                      
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                       (\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{beta}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(\kvw{beta}:\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius});
   \or
    %2: alpha>180,beta<180                  
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                       (\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(\kvw{alpha}:360:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(360:\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius});
   \or
    %3: alpha=0,180,beta>180                      
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                       (180:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(180:\kvw{beta}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(\kvw{beta}:180:\kvw{radius});
   \or
    %4: alpha=0,180,beta=0,180                  
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                       (180:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(180:0:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(0:180:\kvw{radius});
   \or
    %5: alpha=0,180,beta=<180                    
   \or
    %6: alpha<180,beta=>180                    
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                       (180:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(180:\kvw{beta}:\kvw{radius}) 
                       -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(\kvw{beta}:180:\kvw{radius});
   \or
    %7: alpha<180,beta=0,180
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ibeta}{sign(cos(\kvw{beta}))}
    \ifnum\ibeta=1
        \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin] 
                        (180:\kvw{radius}) 
                        -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(180:360:\kvw{radius}) 
                        -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(360:180:\kvw{radius});
    \fi
   \or
    %8: alpha<180,beta<180
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ibeta}{sign(sin(\kvw{alpha})-sin(\kvw{beta}))}
    \ifnum\ibeta=1
       \draw[fill=\kvw{color},very thin]
                        (180:\kvw{radius}) 
                        -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(180:360:\kvw{radius}) 
                        -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(360:180:\kvw{radius});
    \fi
  \fi
  \path[fill=\kvw{color},draw=black] (0,0)--
  (\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{radius})  arc(\kvw{alpha}:\kvw{beta}:\kvw{radius})
                                     --cycle;
}},
wedge/.cd,alpha/.initial=0,beta/.initial=0,%beta > alpha!
color/.initial=blue,
mix color/.initial=gray,radius/.initial=3cm,h/.initial=1cm,
/tikz/.cd,
pics/3d pie chart/.style={code={
  \def\kvw##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d pie chart/##1}}
  \begin{scope}[yscale=\kvw{aspect},transform shape]
    \path[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.8,
           path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent}] 
           (0,-\kvw{h}-\kvw{radius}/4.5) 
           circle[radius=1.05*\kvw{radius}];
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{0}   
    \foreach \XX/\ZZ  in {#1}  
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+\XX}
     \xdef\mysum{\mysum}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{\kvw{alpha0}}
    \foreach \XX/\ZZ [count=\YY starting from 0,remember=\myangle as \myangle] in {#1} 
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangleB}{\myangle+\XX*(360/\mysum)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\kvw{colors}}[\YY]}
     \pic{wedge={alpha=\myangle,beta=\myangleB,color=\mycolor,
        radius/.expanded=\kvw{radius},
        h/.expanded=\kvw{h}
        }};
     \fill (\myangle/2+\myangleB/2:\kvw{radius}*\kvw{eccentricity})
      coordinate (\kvw{cname}-\YY) circle[radius=2pt];
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mysign}{sign(cos(\myangle/2+\myangleB/2))} 
     \draw[thick] (\kvw{cname}-\YY)  -- 
      ++(\myangle/2+\myangleB/2:\kvw{armA}) -- ++ 
      (\mysign*3,0)
      \ifnum\mysign<0
        node[above right,transform shape=false]{\ZZ}
        node[below right,transform shape=false]{\XX\%}
      \else
        node[above left,transform shape=false]{\ZZ}
        node[below left,transform shape=false]{\XX\%}
      \fi;  
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{\myangleB}
    }
    \shade[left color=black,middle color=white,right color=gray,opacity=0.4]
                          (180:\kvw{radius}) 
                          -- ++(0,-\kvw{h}) arc(180:360:\kvw{radius}) 
                          -- ++(0,\kvw{h})  arc(360:180:\kvw{radius});
  \end{scope}                      
}},
3d pie chart/.cd,
colors/.initial={"blue","red","orange","green","yellow"},
radius/.initial=3cm,h/.initial=1cm,alpha0/.initial=0,
aspect/.initial=0.6,eccentricity/.initial=0.7,cname/.initial=c,
armA/.initial=2cm,armB/.initial=3cm
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \path[3d pie chart/.cd, alpha0=45] pic{3d pie chart={36/Nuts,64/Honey}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code  is using `remember=\myangle as \myangle`. It looks a bit fishy to use the same command name (and this also not documentated). It probably worked because of an undocumented side effect (the second command wasn't properly initialized) but with https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/855 this has changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\myangle{45}
\foreach \x [remember=\myangle as \myangle] in{a,b}
{
  \x,\myangle
}

\foreach \x [remember=\myangle as \myanglelast] in{a,b}
{
  \x,\myangle
}
\end{document}
```

gives in texlive 2019

[image]

and in texlive 2021

[image]

This means that you are losing your value as `\myangle` is changed to 0. Imho it would be the best to rewrite the code so that it use two commands. But you could also try this

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangleSTART}{\kvw{alpha0}}
\foreach \XX/\ZZ [count=\YY starting from 0,remember=\myangle as \myangle (initially \myangleSTART)] in {#1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your tex file complies fine in my TeX Live 2021 and generates the following picture:
[image]

Comment: Yes, but `alpha0=45` has no effect on output now. I expect the pie-chart to rotate when the `alpha0` is changed.