# pgfplots: How to use fillbetween correctly at 3D-diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I would like to create something like that (*with pgfplots*):

[image]

How do I have to set the `fill between`'s correctly? 
With different layers?

The tricky part is:

```
% Fill
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=li and lo];
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=li and ui];%
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=lo and uo];
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=ui and uo];
% , on layer= main
% , on layer=axis background
```

Note: *I want to implement the diagram mandatorily with **pgfplots**!* (That means that Plain-TikZ solutions or similar are not wanted.)

[image]

€dit: I added the labels because they could be problematic for different layers.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%\pgfplotsset{layers/standard/.define layer set={background,
%        axis background,axis grid,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,pre
%        main,main,
%        axis descriptions,axis foreground, foreground
%}{}}

% Input
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{\r+3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\h{2}
%
\pgfplotstableread{
Percent   Color              Text
21        red                    1
27        cyan                  2
6        green!80!black   3
46        brown               4
}\tabledata
%
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tabledata}
\pgfmathsetmacro\RowNoMax{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\pgfmathsetmacro\Start{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\End{0}
\newif\ifcapleft

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={thin}]
\begin{axis}[
clip=false,
axis lines=middle, axis equal, hide axis,
y dir=reverse,
samples y=0,
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\RowNoMax}{% =================
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Percent}\of{\tabledata}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Percent{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Color}\of{\tabledata}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Color{"\pgfplotsretval"}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Text}\of{\tabledata}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Text{"\pgfplotsretval"}

  \pgfmathsetmacro\Start{\End}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\End{\Start+\Percent*3.6}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmpLeft{
    ifthenelse(Mod(0.5*(\Start+\End), 360) < 180, 0, 1)}

  \ifnum\tmpLeft=1 \caplefttrue \else \capleftfalse \fi
  \edef\Nanchor{\ifcapleft north west\else north east\fi}
  \edef\Sanchor{\ifcapleft south west\else south east\fi}
  \edef\temp{
%% Draw
\noexpand\addplot3[name path=li, domain=\Start:\End]({\r*sin(x)}, {\r*cos(x)}, {0})  coordinate[pos=0](liStart) coordinate[](liEnd);
\noexpand\addplot3[name path=lo, domain=\Start:\End, fill=none]({\R*sin(x)}, {\R*cos(x)}, {0}) coordinate[pos=0](loStart) coordinate[](loEnd);
%
\noexpand\addplot3[name path=ui, domain=\Start:\End, smooth] ({\r*sin(x)}, {\r*cos(x)}, {\h}) coordinate[pos=0](uiStart) coordinate[](uiEnd) coordinate[pos=0.5](uiMid);
\noexpand\addplot3[name path=uo, domain=\Start:\End, smooth] ({\R*sin(x)}, {\R*cos(x)}, {\h}) coordinate[pos=0](uoStart)  coordinate[](uoEnd) coordinate[pos=0.5](uoMid);
%
\noexpand\draw[fill=none, on layer= axis foreground] (liStart) -- (loStart)  --  (uoStart) -- (uiStart) --cycle;
\noexpand\draw[fill=none] (liEnd) -- (loEnd)  --  (uoEnd) -- (uiEnd) --cycle;
%% Fill
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=li and lo];
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=li and ui];%
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=lo and uo];
\noexpand\addplot[\Color] fill between [of=ui and uo];
% , on layer= main
% , on layer=axis background
% on layer=axis foreground
%% Text
\noexpand\coordinate (Mid) at ($(uiMid)!0.5!(uoMid)$);
\noexpand\coordinate (X) at (Mid -| \ifcapleft-\fi 4cm,0);
%
\unexpanded{\begin{scope}[nodes={inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=2pt, font=\footnotesize}]}
\noexpand\draw[fill] (Mid) circle[radius=2pt] -- (X) node[anchor=\Sanchor] {\Text} node[anchor=\Nanchor] {$\Percent\%$};
\noexpand\end{scope}
}\temp}% =========================
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why pgfplots? This has been already done with plain Ti*k*Z in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59544.

Comment: Plain-TikZ solutions already exist there; I'm looking for a clean pgfplots implementation (and nothing else!).

Comment: There are several reasons why you should avoid 3d-pie charts like the plague. See https://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6?r=US&IR=T and https://www.getnerdyhr.com/3d-pie-charts-are-evil/. The only purpose 3d-pie charts have is honing our TiKz / Pgfplots skills imho.

Comment: I just asking for theoretical interests "how to fill between correctly", lesser for practical usage. ;)