# Errors in passing a previously concatenated string to foreach

Tags: macros, errors, foreach, strings

#### Motivation

While attempting to answer [Pie chart with values as angles not percent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116969/pie-chart-with-values-as-angles-not-percent), I stucked on passing a string to a `foreach`.

#### The context

To makes things clear, I briefly introduce the context. That question asks for degrees rather than percentages in the chart, so my idea was to convert angles into percentages and call then the usual `\pie` command from [`pgf-pie`](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/).

#### The issue

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

%\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\newcommand{\anglepie}[1]{%
  \gdef\elements{}
  \foreach \ang/\lab[count=\xi] in {#1}{
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\perc{(\ang*100)/360}
     \ifnum\xi=1
       \xdef\elements{\perc/\lab}
     \else
       \xdef\elements{\elements, \perc/\lab}
     \fi
  }
  %\pie{\elements} % ideally call this
  \node{\elements};
%  \foreach \x/\y in {\elements}
%  \node[draw] at (\x/10,-1) {\y};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\anglepie{10/A, 20/V, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in principle works because the macro `\elements` contains a string in the right form to be passed to the `foreach` (following the same reasoning of [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/hobby-path-realization-in-convex-hull-approach)). This has been verified thanks to `\node{\elements};`:

[image]

However, uncommenting:

```
\foreach \x/\y in {\elements}
\node[draw] at (\x/10,-1) {\y};
```

rise as errors:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `A' (in '2/A').
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `V' (in '5/V').
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `C' (in '8/C').
```

My feeling is that the string `\elements` is not interpreted correctly by the `foreach`, but I have no clues on the motivation behind. What's going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You need `\expandafter`

```
  \expandafter\pie\expandafter{\elements} % ideally call this
```

Comment: I suspected they were necessary somewhere.. Thanks :)