# concentric ring/donut charts

Tags: plot, charts

I was checking [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/how-can-i-produce-a-ring-or-wheel-chart-like-that-on-page-88-of-the-pgf-manu) and [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82727/create-a-ring-diagram-in-tex), and I was wondering if somebody has a solution to create concentric ring/donut charts

I want to accomplish something like this:
[image: example1]

Or more in particular something like this:
[image: example2]

Because I want to use it for languages and would like to be able to write "汉语" for Chinese...

Does anybody know of a proper way to do it? Many thanks!

Comment: Such representations are bad. They make the outer values look bigger than they are.  E.g. in some of your examples the green ring looks larger than the yellow.

Comment: How about a concentric pie chart?

Comment: Google for "pie charts evil".

Comment: I don't know how a concentric pie chart will solve Ulrike's comment, but [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159876/1952) you have an example.

Comment: Nice colors; but a reader will mentally unwind the bars, so thinking that Turkey (in the smallest version of the diagram) performs better than Iceland. Pie charts are not evil *per se*; they surely become bad when “three dimensional”.

Comment: Any recommendation for a fancy way to show my level in different languages, other than a regular bar plot?

Comment: I guess I will just make it simple and make some circles with relative sizes like in https://d1hk1zhcb5hn6i.cloudfront.net/5759225890d761fc41ddf247/v/0/pdf-converted-cache/style-preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregarding the recommendations to *not use this kind of diagram*, it's fairly straightforward to draw those kinds of things, just a matter of drawing some `arc`s. I didn't try matching the colors, or making any sort of nice interface.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\i] \total/\clr in {80/blue,60/red,45/green,25/cyan}
   \draw [line width=2mm,\clr]
     (0.5cm+\i*3mm,0)
     node[above,inner sep=0pt,black,font=\scriptsize]{\total}
     arc[start angle=0,radius=0.5cm+\i*3mm,delta angle=-3.60*\total];
\matrix [every node/.style={right=1.5mm,black,font=\small}] at (2,2) {
   \fill[blue] circle[radius=2mm] node  {Iceland}; \\
   \fill[red] circle[radius=2mm] node  {Switzerland}; \\
   \fill[green] circle[radius=2mm] node  {USA}; \\
   \fill[cyan] circle[radius=2mm] node  {Turkey}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\i] \total/\clr in {10/cyan,20/green,30/red,50/blue}
   \draw [line width=2mm,\clr]
     (-0.5cm-\i*2.5mm,0)
%     node[above,inner sep=0pt,black,font=\scriptsize]{\total}
     arc[start angle=180,radius=0.5cm+\i*2.5mm,delta angle=3.60*\total];

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,anchor=south west,inner sep=0.5pt,xshift=-2mm,font=\scriptsize}]
\node [cyan] (I) at (0,0.2) {Italian};
\node [green] (F) at (I.north west) {French};
\node [red] (E) at (F.north west) {English};
\node [blue] (H) at (E.north west) {Hungarian};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

Each ring is placed in a separate `\wheelchart`.

The value (used in the key `total angle`) and the color (used in the key `slices style`) are defined in the `\foreach` loop. The counter `\n` of this loop is used in the key `radius` which sets the inner radius to `1+\n` and the outer radius to `2+\n`. Hereafter, these radii are modified with the key `gap radius` to create the gap between the rings.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\WCvalue/\WCcolor [count=\n] in {80/Yellow,60/Green,40/Blue,25/Red}{
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  gap radius=0.1,
  radius={1+\n}{2+\n},
  slices style=\WCcolor,
  start angle=0,
  total angle={\WCvalue*3.6}
]{1}
\node[above] at ({1.5+\n},0) {$\WCvalue$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `wheelchart` looks great (are you the author?), but could you slow down a little so new questions don't get immediately bumped from the front page?

Comment: Thank you. I will post some more answers but at a lower speed.

Comment: Sounds great - thanks!