# TikZ: Drawing an image from the Manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good night,

I've been studying a bit more about LaTeX, more specifically about TikZ and how to create images with it and I've come across this image on the manual:

[image: Page 90 from the manual available at CTAN]

The image above is on the 90th page of the manual (V 2.10).

The image above got my interest because I might teach statistics next semester and this could be a different way of showing data to my students but I didn't find it's code in the manual so I could study it (I'm afraid of having missed it though).

How can I draw something similar to that in TikZ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/how-can-i-produce-a-ring-or-wheel-chart-like-that-on-page-88-of-the-pgf-manu

Comment: Consider updating your TeX distribution. The old version of TikZ lacks many features and bug fixes.

Comment: @cfr How can I check my TeX distribution's version and how to update?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=7|1.1814).