# How to draw a pie chart open in the middle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

I am wondering, how I can draw the Pie diagram as is shown on page 50 of the TikZ manual here [enter link description here](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf)? It's a 2D pie chart that is opened in the middle. Here is a snapshot of it:

> [image]

Comment: You can check accepted answer for this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/how-can-i-produce-a-ring-or-wheel-chart-like-that-on-page-88-of-the-pgf-manu

Comment: @Adarsh , wow. Thank you - I search and I couldn't find it by myself!

Comment: @AboAmmar , thanks a lot for adding the Figure and the solution!