# Drawing the chart from tikz/pgf Manual

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

In the manual [1] on page 90, there are two charts shown. The upper one is of interest for me. (The cyclic with the percentages. It's like a loading bar.)

Could someone point me, how I could draw that? If there is the code somewhere in the manual, tell me. I wasn't able to find that.

[1a] http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf (old)
[1b] http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf (actual)

Comment: First, that manual is old, if you're using a somewhat recent version of TikZ, don't use that as a reference. Second: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82727/create-a-ring-diagram-in-tex/82729

Comment: Added the latest reference. Thanks for that linked thread. It comes close to that, what I want to realize. In the latest ref. it's on page 94, there is some spacings (white lines). Well I see, this thread links itselve on others with that solution I'm looking for. Thanks. I didn't know the name of that chart so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found on [How can I produce a 'ring (or wheel) chart' like that on page 88 of the PGF manual?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/how-can-i-produce-a-ring-or-wheel-chart-like-that-on-page-88-of-the-pgf-manu/18105#18105)

and I cite the solution:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.8cm}
\def\outerradius{2.2cm}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
    \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
        \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % The text in the center of the wheel
      \node[align=center,text width=2*\innerradius]{Ratings given by \pgfmathprintnumber{\totalnum}~participants};

      % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

      % Rotate so we start from the top
      \begin{scope}[line width=\wheelwidth,rotate=90]

      % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
      \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

            % Calculate the percent value
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
            % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

            % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
            \pgfmathparse{
               (-\midangle<5?"south":
                (-\midangle<85?"south west":
                 (-\midangle<105?"west":
                  (-\midangle<175?"north west":
                   (-\midangle<185?"north":
                    (-\midangle<265?"north east":
                     (-\midangle<275?"east":
                      (-\midangle<355?"south east":"south")
                     )
                    )
                   )
                  )
                 )
                )
               )
            } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}

            % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
            \draw[\colour] (-\cumnum:\midradius pt) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\midradius pt);

            % Draw the data labels
            \node at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\name: \value\ (\pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%)};

            % The 'spokes'
            \foreach \i in {0,...,\value} {
                \draw [gray,thin] (-\cumnum-\i/\totalnum*360:\innerradius) -- (-\cumnum-\i/\totalnum*360:\outerradius);
            }

            % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }

      \end{scope}
      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Usage:

```
\wheelchart{20/green/good,  10/yellow/medium, 9/red/bad, 5/white/neutral, 8/blue/ok}
```